# Why is flatMap on a Vector[Option[Int]] whose mapper function result is not a Vector[Option[Int]] valid?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, flatmap

For example,

```
Vector(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None).flatMap{
  n => n
}
```

produces a `Vector(1, 2, 3)` instead of giving an error. As I have seen in other languages, `flatMap` is used when you have a mapper function that produces nesting so I would expect this to be a valid `flatMap`:

```
Vector(1, 2, 3).flatMap{
  eachNum => Vector(eachNum)
}
```

My mapper function produces a `Vector` which would cause nesting (i.e. `Vector(Vector(1), Vector(2), Vector(3), Vector(4))`) if I used a `map` due to the container wrapping. However, `flatMap` will remove this nesting and flatten it. This makes sense when there is nesting of two identical monads.

However, I do not understand how using a `flatMap` with a mapper function that returns an `Option` makes a `Vector[Option[Int]]` become a `Vector[Int]`. Is there some sort of transformation going on (I have never seen this before), could someone explain and perhaps point me to some resources?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

we can use `reify` to see what is going on:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> val v = Vector(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None)
v: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Option[Int]] = Vector(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None)

scala> reify { v.flatMap(x => x) }
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] =
    Expr[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]]($read.v.flatMap(((x) =>
     Option.option2Iterable(x)))(Vector.canBuildFrom))
```

This is showing us that it is using the option2Iterable conversion to convert the `Option` to `Iterable`, and `Iterable` is a subtype of the `GenTraversableOnce` type that flatMap is expecting.

Comment: I commented on the other answer, just a plug for `:replay -Xprint:typer`.

Comment: This is a great explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The function `f` passed within the `flatMap` here:

```
Vector(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None).flatMap{
    n => n
}
```

Is a function `A => GenTraversableOnce[B]` as described in the `flatMap` implementation:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f : scala.Function1[A, GenTraversableOnce[B]])
                    (implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That])
                    : That = ???
```

The function implemented in your example `n => n` is:

```
(n: Option[Int]) => n
```

Where `A` is `Option[Int]` and `B` is `Int`.

Because `CanBuildFrom` is defined as `trait CanBuildFrom[-From, -Elem, +To]`:

- `From` is `Repr`, and in this case `Vector`
- `Elem` is `B` so `Int`

The result of `flatMap` is therefore `Vector[Int]`

Comment: Compile with `-Xprint:typer` to see `Option.option2Iterable` at work.