# Figuring out chain of implicit invocations

Tags: scala

Is there any way how can I figure out the whole implicit chain (and I am interested in all of the implicit kinds). I'm using IntelliJ Idea, but I'm searching for any way to do that, even if I have to work with another IDE. (and I'm wondering whether REPL can help me with that)

For example I write `a gt b` where `gt` comes from `scalaz`. And I want to know:

1. Exactly what implicit instance of `Order` was used
2. What typeclass was used (I know the answer in this particular instance - it's easy in scalaz, but in general sometimes it not always that obvious)
3. Whole chain how `a` received a method `gt`. For this particular example, I know that `ToOrderOps` trait was used, but in general I may not know that and I also can't figure out how `ToOrderOps` was imported.

Comment: Looking at @stew's previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34735993/409976), maybe you want [reify](https://gist.github.com/kevinmeredith/396cea7839fababa7e2a)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the Scala reflection API in the REPL is usually a good way to start this kind of investigation:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.reify

scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> println(reify(1 gt 2))
Expr[Boolean](Scalaz.ToOrderOps(1)(Scalaz.intInstance).gt(2))

scala> println(reify("a" gt "b"))
Expr[Boolean](Scalaz.ToOrderOps("a")(Scalaz.stringInstance).gt("b"))
```

The `ToOrderOps` here is a method, not the trait, and the `Scalaz` indicates that you're seeing it because `scalaz.Scalaz` mixes in the `ToOrderOps` trait, so I think this approach addresses all three of your points.

Comment: I just wanted to mention how awesome you are. Thanks! :)